# How to remotely connect python tcp client and server?

Tags: python, tcp, server, client

I have just written some python server and client using tcp protocol. I am using linux, and want to connect to a windows machine which isn't in my local network. How can i do that? I know it is something about NAT, but i can't find out how to do it properly. Could you please give me step by step guide? Thanks.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sockets? You need to ensure that the network the windows laptop is on is configured to forward a specified port to the laptop. (means it can be accessed externally) You can then use sockets to connect to the laptop on the port you designate.

Comment: How can I do it using python script? I want it to configure the network in the moment the script is launched on windows machine. Maybe cmd command?

Comment: Port forwarding is best done on the router not a python script. It is possible using a Python script, however not simple - take a look http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483732-asynchronous-port-forwarding/

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you also tell me how to do it using cmd?

Comment: I think the last question: with what should I replace connectadress, connectport, listenadress and listenport?

Comment: "listenport" and "connectport" are the ports you are using, so im guessing 22 for both? listenaddress" and "connectaddress" listen address is the laptops IP and connect is your python server IP.

Comment: and if this answers your question feel free to mark it as the answer